# How to disable Rule: one-line in TSLint

Tags: tslint

```
 clearFile()
 {
      (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('uploadFile')).value = "";
 }
```

Gives

```
[tslint] misplaced opening brace
```

.

And if I use the opening braces in same line of function, it doesn't give me warning like

```
clearFile(){
      (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('uploadFile')).value = "";
 }
```

This rule is called "one-line" rule 
And how to configure it in TSLint to handle first type of braces style

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to globally turn of Goto {ProjectDirectoty}/tslint.json and add "one-line" : false in rules

One-line has 5 sub rules as "check-catch", "check-finally", "check-else", "check-open-brace", "check-whitespace". You can understand it from name, like for catch you should or not write opening braces in same or next line.

```
{
"extends": "../tslint.json",
"rules": {
    "one-line" : false,
    "directive-selector": [
        true,
        "attribute",
        "app",
        "camelCase"
    ],
    "component-selector": [
        true,
        "element",
        "app",
        "kebab-case"
    ]
}
```

}

If you want to turn off only specific subrule, use something like this

```
"one-line": [true, "check-catch", "check-finally", "check-else"]
```

It will turn on for these 3 rules and off for other 2 rules

And if you want to disable in a particular file

```
/* tslint:disable:rule1 rule2 rule3... */ in that file
```